# Schedule a blog post (not Blogger, not WordPress)

Tags: php, mysql, blogs, schedule

I have been searching online for a tutorial but I guess we can say that search engines are "polluted" with WordPress and Blogger.

Here is my problem:

I followed [this tutorial](http://girlswhogeek.com/category/tutorials/build-a-blog) and it went quite well, everything works as I wanted. But now I would like to have a function where the admin (that is writing a new blog entry) has the option to decide when is the blog entry going to be on-line (hh/dd/yy).

Does anyone know of a tutorial, demo, tips, whatever that can help?

I know I could use Blogger or WordPress, but I don't want to. This would have the additional purpose of learning some more PHP.

Comment: Hard to say when we cant see table defintions and so on, but : Add a `timestamp` field to your articles table, say `published`, and let the user edit that field when editing / creating a new article. Then alter the code so only published articles will be shown eg "select articles where published<current_timestamp", this would provide the desired feature.

Comment: @davidkonrad is right. I built my own blog as well, and this is exactly how I handle it. You just need to check the timestamp against the current time when you're outputting the posts. If the publish timestap is >= current time, publish it.

Comment: davidkonrad, that is a very good start, but due to my knowledge in PHP and MySQL it will not be enough. Here you can see the table (http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2004/part-1-create-your-database) and here you can see another table (http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2007/part-11-categories)

Comment: relentless could I get an example or a link with one? Perhaps a forum, or tutorial? I don't know that much PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the "Build a Blog" articles. It seems to me that you do not need to change very much. Here is some kind of recipe / hint / suggestion :

### Part 1 - "create your database"

Change the "whole script" to

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE php_blog (
  id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  timestamp int(20) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  entry longtext NOT NULL,
  published date, <--- this is the change
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)";
```

Use a tool like PHPMyadmin if you want to alter an existing table.

### Part 2 - "post to your db"

Add this inside `<form>` :

```
<input type="text" name="published" id="published" value="" />
```

### Part 2b - "post to your db"

Inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` add

```
$published = $_POST['published'];
```

Additional, right after - if the user has not entered a publish-date, *that **must** be in the form m/d/y* :

```
if ($published=='') $published = date("m/d/Y");
```

Change the SQL :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO php_blog (timestamp,title,entry,published) VALUES ('$timestamp','$title','$entry','$published')";
```

### Part 3 - "display entries"

Change the SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE id='$id' and published<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP LIMIT 1";
```

---

## NOTE : Completely untested!

This is only to point to a start / give a kind of recipe.

The "Build a Blog" system is very, *very* simple, so I think its pretty much that. If you get it to work, you will need more coding regarding the next chapters, but I hope it could be a starting point. I like the idea of people trying to make their own tool themselves, and in the process learn how to do it. Much better.

If you started with a blog system like WordPress, you would just meet another kind of problems - most likely even more frustrating. It is better to have control, rather than waste the time to correct other people's coding mistakes.

Comment: Even if it is not tested, this is the best I could get. This much I wasn't expecting! You are probably the nicest person I ever "met" in here and for that I am truly thankful!! I hope I can repay you this some how... If I find any "bugs" I will try to work them out! THANKS

Comment: Well, happy to help - but wait to accept before you actually have got it to work. As I said, I have only read the articles - and added code to where a published-field is "missing" for the first basic articles. But write if you get it to work, or not. I could not find a "download complete sourcecode" or similar, so I could not test it for sure. That would have been better.